# Property doesn't exist after initialization

Tags: ios, swift

I have these properties in my view controller class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var flashCardView: FlashCard!

var originPoint: CGPoint!
var xFromCenter: Float = 0
var yFromCenter: Float = 0
let actionMargin: Double = 240      
let rotationMax: Float = 1        
let rotationStrength: Float = 320  
let rotationAngle: Float = 3.14/8  
var memories: [Memory] {
    if let loadedMemory = self.loadMemory() {
        return loadedMemory.sorted(by: {$0.strength < $1.strength})
    } else {
        let sampleMemory = Memory(masteryLevel: 1, algorithm: Algorithm.algorithm1.chooseAlgorithm(), forgetRatio: 0, lastStudyTime: Date(), front: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Ideas-Blue"), back: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Ideas-Yellow"))
        return [sampleMemory]
    }
}
var unfamiliarity: Int = 0
```

I set a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` to inspect the values of them, but interestingly, every variable showed up in the debugger except the computed property - `memories` is missing, like this:

[image]

**Question:**

Why is it missing, shouldn't all properties of a class get initialized before `viewDidLoad` gets called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> shouldn't all properties of a class get initialized before viewDidLoad
>   gets called?

No, referring to Swift [Documentation - Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html):

Computed properties:

> which do not actually store a value. Instead, they provide a getter
>   and an optional setter to retrieve and set other properties and values
>   indirectly.

Means that by definition, you cannot set a value for a computed property by default because simply its computed! (its value should be based on -let's say- other stored properties values).

Once you access (or "re-acceess") it, it should do the computation.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Computed properties do not occupy space in memory. So there is no reason of getting them initialized. It will be computed when you access the property.